# Ethernet device communication with Socket. Would this general class work?

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket, ethernet

I'm trying to write a class for communicating with hardware using the socket protocol. The class is to be fairly general so that I can write custom classes for each device on my network that inherit the general communication protocol class.

I'm new to socket programming and wonder if anyone can suggest hints or improvements to the following code please?

In particular I'd like to clarify:

1) Is it true that sockets only exist for one transaction and then are destroyed once the device has returned a complete message. Hence my need for open and close socket methods.

2) My readout is for an unknown message length. pySocket documentation recommends adding a length indicator to messages, although the hardware I'm communicating with doesn't permit me to modify how it sends data. Therefore, I thought reading out for a maximum of 1 kbyte seemed reasonable for now, but I could always increase later if needed.

```
class SocketTalker(object):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, timeout=3):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.timeout = timeout

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout)

    def open_socket(self):
        self.sock.connect((self.ip, self.port))

    def close_socket(self):
        self.sock.shutdown()
        self.sock.close()

    def query(self, command):
        self.open_socket()
        self.sock.send(command)
        data = self.sock.recv(1024) # Wait for up to 1 kbyte of data to be returned (if fewer bytes returned and the instrument signals message complete, the socket terminates and this data is returned)
        self.close_socket() # Double check the socket is closed after use
    return data
```

Thanks.